# Intermittent problems with ftp_nlist

Tags: php, ftp, file-listing

I have the following code.  Sometimes it runs without a problem, and other times it doesn't. Nothing changes in the code between the times it runs and fails.  When it fails, the ftp_nlist count comes back with a file count of one.  I know there are more than that in the directory.  when we first discovered the problem, it would fail once every couple of weeks.  Now it is failing on a daily basis.

Does anyone know what is going wrong or what I could look at to get this issue fixed?

```
$conn = ftp_connect(RECORDINGS_FTP_HOST);
if(!$conn) {
    write_log_line("ABORTED: Could not connect to server:" . RECORDINGS_FTP_HOST . "\r\n", LOG_FILE);
    exit;
}
if(!ftp_login($conn,RECORDINGS_FTP_USER,RECORDINGS_FTP_PASSWD)) {
    write_log_line("ABORTED: Could not log in to server:" . RECORDINGS_FTP_HOST . "\r\n", LOG_FILE);
    ftp_quit($conn); 
    exit;
}   
ftp_pasv($conn, true);

// Download file list
$files = ftp_nlist($conn,"-t " . ARCHIVED_RECORDINGS); // -t means bring in the oldest first. So it will get processed first.
write_log_line("Files found " . count($files) ."\r\n", LOG_FILE);
```

Comment: have you tried `ftp_chdir` first an then `ftp_nlist($conn, ".")`. And what result you get with `ftp_rawlist`?

Comment: I haven't tried those, will give them a go and see what happens.